# how to do sort_by value when it's nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4

How to avoid comparision with nil?
I want the nil value to be the last element when sorting:

```
hash.sort_by{|k,v| [v.present? ? v : 99999999]}
```

Comment: Are these integer or floating point values?

Comment: Please add the  actual input and desired output.

Comment: `hash.sort_by { |k,v| v || Float::INFINITY }.to_h`

Answer (score 3):

Your question isn't clear, but as I understand, this should help you.

```
#> hash
#=> {:b=>nil, :c=>4, :v=>7}

hash.sort_by { |_,value| value || Float::INFINITY }.to_h
#=> {:c=>4, :v=>7, :b=>nil}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[2, 5, 1, nil, 7, 3, nil, nil, 4, 6].sort_by { |i| [i ? 0 : 1, i] }
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, nil, nil, nil]
```

Comment: Nice, but you should briefly explain what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

```
 hash.sort_by{|k,v| [v ? v : 99999999]}.to_h
```

Comment: But what if the hash contains a number above 99,999,999? It would appear after the `nil` values.